# Ruby on rails: Session/current_user, db-insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having problems with an insert to the database. First an explanation of my little Blog app.

The models: Users och Posts. http://pastie.org/2694864
A post have columns: title, body, user id

3 controllers:
Session, Application (with current_user) and PostController: http://pastie.org/2695386

My loggin session seems to work but when a logged in user shoult write a post the database doesn't recognize any user_id. It's just set to nil. rails console:

```
=> #<Post id: 17, title: "hello", body: "hello world", created_at: "2011-10-14 14:54:25", updated_at: "2011-10-14 14:54:25", user_id: nil>
```

I guess it's in the post controller line 88 this should be fixed but I can't figure it out.
I have also tried:

```
    @post = Post.new(params[:post], :user_id => session[:user_id])
```

But the user_id stills sets to nil!

This is my first app so I would be really greatful for detaild answears.

Tanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing `Post.new` two arguments (two hashes in this case), but it only takes one argument. Try this:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post].merge!(:user_id => session[:user_id]))
```